# Dominance of exponential moment due to Stochastic dominance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are positive random variables such that $P(X\geq x)\leq P(Y\geq x)$ and let $\lambda >0$

Then can we say $$E(e^{\lambda X})\leq \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{\lambda x}P(Y\geq x)\,dx $$

*My attempt:-*

Well, I'll assume everything to be finite to avoid complications.

I can say that $$E(e^{\lambda X})\leq E(e^{\lambda Y})=\int_{0}^{\infty}P(e^{\lambda Y}\geq t)\,dx$$ But I don't see how to get $e^{\lambda x}$ from the above.

Another way I tried is $$P(X\geq x)=P(e^{\lambda X}\geq e^{\lambda x})\leq e^{-\lambda x}E(e^{\lambda X}\mathbf{1}_{X\geq x})$$ but this alters the direction of the inequalities.

Well, I don't know if the bound that I said above is at all true or not.

I simply want to find the best possible bound. So I will get $\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda e^{\lambda x}P(X\geq x)\,dx=E(e^{\lambda X})-1$. Which would lead me to the bound $1+\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda e^{\lambda x}P(Y\geq x)\,dx$ . I simply want to know if this bound can be improved.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would it help if $E(e^{\lambda X})\leq \lambda \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{\lambda x}P(Y\geq x)dx$? Not sure if this holds without the extra $\lambda$

Comment: Yeah this is the bound I get by substitution and also there has to be an additional $+\lambda$.

Comment: I'm indeed missing a $+\lambda$, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: I don't think the missing $\lambda$ resolves this, because the relation obviously has to hold for $Y = X$ as well, but $$ \mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda X}] = \int_{t = 0}^\infty P(e^{\lambda X} \ge t) \mathrm{d}t= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \lambda e^{\lambda u} P(X \ge u) \mathrm{d}u,$$ so you're missing the branch from $-\infty$ to $0$ in the integral.

E.g., for $X \sim \mathrm{Unif}[0,1]$, $ \mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda X}] = (e^{\lambda} - 1)/\lambda,$ but $ \int_0^\infty \lambda e^{\lambda x} P(X \ge x) = \int_0^1 \lambda e^{\lambda x} (1-x) = (e^{\lambda} - 1 - \lambda)/\lambda$.

Comment: Of course, if $X \ge 0,$ then the missing branch just evaluates to $1$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 and others. Well I have said in the question body that I don't know if this bound is true or not. I simply want to find the best possible bound. So I will get $\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda e^{\lambda x}P(X\geq x)\,dx=E(e^{\lambda X})-1$. Which would lead me to the bound $1+\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda e^{\lambda x}P(Y\geq x)\,dx$ . I simply want to know if this bound can be improved. I'll edit this part in the quesion too.